# How to interpret standardised coefficients with a log transformed dependent variable

Tags: regression-coefficients, logarithm

I am running a linear regression (random effects GLS) with a log transformed dependent variable and a non-log-transformed independent variable. I am using standardised coefficients. The standardised coefficient of that linear dependent variable is -0.156. I know when the dependent variable is log transformed one needs to calculate e^(coefficient) which would be in my case e^(-0.156). When the coefficient is standardised the interpretation is usually: a 1 standard deviation increase in X leads to a x standard deviation increase in Y. Whereas with a log transformation the interpretation is: a 1% increase in X leads to an x% increase in Y. How would I now correctly interpret my standardised coefficient?
Is it: A 1 standard deviation increase in X leads to a o.144 standard deviation decrease in Y.
Or: A 1 standard deviation increase in X leads to a o.144% decrease in standard deviation of Y.
Or do I not take e^(coefficient) in this case and just use the -0.156?

Thank you very much for your help!!